# apply a function to columns in Pandas raises AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have the following `dict` and pandas `DataFrame`.

```
sample_dict = {'isDuplicate': {'1051681551': False, '1037545402': True, '1035390559': False},
               'dateTime': {'1051681551': Timestamp('2019-01-29 09:09:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
               '1037545402': Timestamp('2019-01-11 02:06:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
               '1035390559': Timestamp('2019-01-08 14:35:00+0000', tz='UTC')},
               'dateTimePub': {'1051681551': None, '1037545402': None, '1035390559': None}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict)
```

I want to apply a `np.where()` function to `dateTime`and `dateTimePub` columns like:

```
def _replace_datetime_with_datetime_pub(news_dataframe):
    news_dataframe.dateTime = np.where(news_dataframe.dateTimePub, news_dataframe.dateTimePub, news_dataframe.dateTime)
    return pd.to_datetime(news_dataframe.dateTime)

df.apply(_replace_datetime_with_datetime_pub)
```

But I get the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dateTimePub'
```

It's possible to do `df = _replace_datetime_with_datetime_pub(df)`. But my question is,

- how to apply this function via either `pd.DataFrame.apply` or `pd.DataFrame.transform` method, and
- why do I get this error?

I have already checked many other similar questions, but none of them had `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `apply`, you're breaking down your DataFrame into series to pass to your function. Since you don't specify the axis keyword argument, pandas assumes you want to pass each column as a series. This is the source of the `AttributeError` you're getting. For pandas to pass each row as a series, you want to specify `axis=1` in your `apply` call.

Even then, you'll need to adapt the function some to fit it into the `apply` paradigm. In particular, you want to think of how the function should process each row it encounters. The function you pass to `apply` (if you specify `axis=1`) will work on each row in isolation from every other row. The return value from each row will then be stitched together to return a series.